# Create an unit test for an HashCode method

Tags: c#, xunit

I have the following HashCode helper:

```
public struct HashCode {

  private readonly Int32 Value;

  private HashCode(Int32 value) {
    Value = value;
  }

  public static implicit operator Int32(HashCode hashCode) {
    return hashCode.Value;
  }

  public static HashCode Of<T>(T item) {
    return new HashCode(GetHashCode(item));
  }

  public HashCode And<T>(T item) {
    return new HashCode(CombineHashCodes(Value, GetHashCode(item)));
  }

  public HashCode AndEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) {      
    Int32 hashCode = items.Select(x => GetHashCode(x)).Aggregate((x, y) => CombineHashCodes(x, y));
    return new HashCode(CombineHashCodes(Value, hashCode));
  }

  private static Int32 CombineHashCodes(Int32 x, Int32 y) {

    // Taken from:
    https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/mscorlib/src/System/Tuple.cs#L56

    unchecked {        
      return ((x << 5) + x) ^ y;
    }
  }

  private static Int32 GetHashCode<T>(T item) {
    return item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode();
  }

}
```

I use it as follows:

```
HashCode.Of(value1).And(value2).AndEach(collection);
```

How should I create an Unit Test to test this HashCode?

Comment: Unit tests verify a behavior is true, you can't create a test until you you decide which behaviors you want to verify. Ask your self "For my code to work HashCode must _______" then for every blank you write a unit test that makes sure that the statement is true.

Comment: Basically I would like to test "HashCode.Of(value1)", HashCode.Of(value1).And(value2) and HashCode.Of(value1).And(value2).AndEach(collection); I need to check if the HashCode is different ... I think I should repeat a few iterations? Not sure how to start this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one or two classes that have hardcoded `HashCode`s then depending on how much granular unit tests you want create a test/tests that computes hash codes using your helper:

```
var result = HashCode
  .Of(new HardcodedHashCode(5))
  .And(new HardcodedHashCode(1));

Assert.Equals(result, manually_computed_value);
```

for every usage of HashCode helper you must compute expected hash code *manually*. I suggest one test for `Of`, `And` and for `AndEach`, plus single test that uses all of them.

EDIT more code:

```
public class HardcodedHashCode {
  private readonly int _hashCode;

    public HardcodedHashCode(int hashCode) { _hashCode = hashCode; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => _hashCode; 
}

// example test
public void and_combines_hashcodes_using_xyz_method() {
   var h1 = new HardcodedHashCode(1);
   var h5 = new HardcodedHashCode(5);

   int combinedHashcode = HashCode.of(h1).And(h5);

   // sorry but can't force myself to compute manually in the evening
   Assert.Equals(_manually_compute_value_here_, combinedHashcode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should warn you that you maybe trying to use GetHashCode method a bit incorrectly. You are mixing .NET hashing with your own hashing. And I suppose your hashing has different goals than .NET hashing.

At first I should mention that every .NET object has it own hash code and it should not change after the object is created.

`object[] data = new object[] { 1, new Random(), 5 };
int hash1 = HashCode.AndEach(data);
data[2] = "123";
int hash2 = HashCode.AndEach(data);`

I assume that hash1 != hash2. For [.NET hashing it is fail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/).

That's why your `HashCode.GetHashCode` implementation can produce very interesting results in combination with any deferred-execution (such as Linq).

In addition there is [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx), which says:

> A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in collections that are based on a hash table. **A hash code is not a permanent value**.
>
> ...
>
> - Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases.

For example the implementation of `Object.GetHashCode` in .NET CLR 2.0 and .NET CLR 4.5 differs. That's why your unit tests result can be different in .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.5 if you add any object in your test that uses `Object.GetHashCode` method.

> If you override the GetHashCode method, you should also override Equals, and vice versa.

So the code provided by csharpfolk is not entirely correct for class `HardcodedHashCode`. If two objects are equal, their hash codes MUST be equal (it is from hash definition). The `HardcodedHashCode` should override Equals method or somebody can create unit-test which is wrong for .NET hashing.

So I'd recommend to eliminate any calls of `Object.GetHashCode` from your code. Or make sure that your code does not violate guidelines from Microsoft.